# Build failed with an exception. Error: Couldn't find constructor 'LoginScreen'. nextScreen: const LoginScreen(), while development in bitbucket

Tags: flutter, deployment, flutter-dependencies

I am facing issuse in build, while deployment in bitbucket. showing error, while its working fine and apk building fine in  local.

[image]

[image]

Expecting it apk to also build in deployment